# reactions counted multiple times? discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a bot where if you type a command it will send a message and if you react to that message it will send another message but if i run the command again and react to the first message it will send the message two times how can i fix that?

```html
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user)=>{
                    if(user.bot) return;
                  if (reaction.emoji.name === '⛔') {
                      clearInterval(my_interval);
                      clearTimeout(my_timeout);
                      const exampleEmbed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('#fefefe')
              .setTitle(`Your record was ${index}s!`)
              .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL())
              .setDescription('Bot made by tempacc')
              if(run){ 
                  message.channel.send(exampleEmbed1);
                  index = 0;
                  message.member.voice.channel.leave();
                  run = false;
                  }else if(!run){
                      message.channel.send('You must start a speedrun before running this command!');
                  }
                  }
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested that you should use a reaction collector instead, but I will include an example here along with docs for anyone else wondering.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === ''; // Check reaction was a  and not anything else
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```

However where `time` is, you can also pass `max`, `maxUsers` or `maxEmojis` into this data object, for example:

```js
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { maxUsers: 1 });
```

You can find more about the reaction collector [here](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) and more about the options [here](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ReactionCollectorOptions)